# Installing Nginx-extras module, downgrade nginx-1.20 to 1.14 on Debian 10

Tags: nginx

I've installed Nginx 1.20 on Debian 10 following this :

[Nginx on Debian](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#Debian)

I need to install `Nginx-extras`, but after `sudo apt-get install -y nginx-extras`
when I check `Nginx -v` it returns 1.14.2 ... (In Ubuntu 20 it downgrade from 1.20 to 1.18)

More Info: When I install Nginx on Debian using default repository, version 1.14.2 will be installed. In my `.conf` file I need to use `delay` like this:

```
limit_req zone=server_ratelimit burst=800 delay=500;
```

, so get the error :

> This version (1.14) not supporting `delay`

So, I purged Nginx and installed 1.20 version. Now adding some directives, I need to install `Nginx-extras`, after installing this module, when I check the Nginx version, it shows 1.14, but `delay` throw no errors, it means that the version is not 1.14 ?!

I need to know, what is the real version of my Nginx? If it is 1.14 so why `delay` throw no error, If it is 1.20 why the `Nginx -v` returns 1.14 ??

**Update 1** :

`apt-cache show nginx-extras Package:` returns :

```
Package: nginx-extras
Source: nginx
Version: 1.14.2-2+deb10u3
Installed-Size: 1277
Maintainer: Debian Nginx Maintainers <pkg-nginx-maintainers@alioth-lists.debian.net>
Architecture: amd64
Provides: httpd, httpd-cgi, nginx
Depends: libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u3), libnginx-mod-http-cache-purge (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u3), libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u3), libnginx-mod-http-echo (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u3), libnginx-mod-http-fancyindex (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u3), libnginx-mod-http-geoip (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u3), libnginx-mod-http-headers-more-filter (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u3), libnginx-mod-http-image-filter (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u3), libnginx-mod-http-lua (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u3), libnginx-mod-http-perl (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u3), libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u3), libnginx-mod-http-uploadprogress (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u3), libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u3), libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u3), libnginx-mod-mail (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u3), libnginx-mod-nchan (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u3), libnginx-mod-stream (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u3), nginx-common (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u3), libc6 (>= 2.28), libpcre3, libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
Suggests: nginx-doc (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u3)
Conflicts: nginx-full, nginx-light
Breaks: nginx (<< 1.4.5-1)
Description-en: nginx web/proxy server (extended version)
 Nginx ("engine X") is a high-performance web and reverse proxy server
 created by Igor Sysoev. It can be used both as a standalone web server
 and as a proxy to reduce the load on back-end HTTP or mail servers.
 .
 This package provides a version of nginx with the standard modules, plus
 extra features and modules such as the Perl module, which allows the
 addition of Perl in configuration files.
 .
 STANDARD HTTP MODULES: Core, Access, Auth Basic, Auto Index, Browser, Empty
 GIF, FastCGI, Geo, Limit Connections, Limit Requests, Map, Memcached, Proxy,
 Referer, Rewrite, SCGI, Split Clients, UWSGI.
 .
 OPTIONAL HTTP MODULES: Addition, Auth Request, Charset, WebDAV, FLV, GeoIP,
 Gunzip, Gzip, Gzip Precompression, Headers, HTTP/2, Image Filter, Index, Log,
 MP4, Embedded Perl, Random Index, Real IP, Slice, Secure Link, SSI, SSL,
 Stream, SSL Preread, Stub Status, Substitution, Thread Pool, Upstream,
 User ID, XSLT.
 .
 MAIL MODULES: Mail Core, Auth HTTP, Proxy, SSL, IMAP, POP3, SMTP.
 .
 THIRD PARTY MODULES: Auth PAM, Cache Purge, DAV Ext, Echo, Fancy Index,
 Headers More, Embedded Lua, HTTP Substitutions, Nchan, Upload Progress,
 Upstream Fair Queue.
Description-md5: 225aac32714dab461692d2628eac8f17
Homepage: https://nginx.net
Section: httpd
Priority: optional
Filename: pool/main/n/nginx/nginx-extras_1.14.2-2+deb10u3_amd64.deb
Size: 515148
MD5sum: 63868ff73f9ea92b604394fb2b793be2
SHA256: bc67168fb3a20bda1d9c50fc56a65dbeb04da9cd8046faac2e0bead1f6035e81
```

`dpkg -s nginx-extras | grep '^Version:'` returns:

> Version: 1.14.2-2+deb10u3

And good to know that, after installing `sudo apt-get install -y nginx-extras`, still get error on Debian 10 (Not Ubuntu) :

> unknown directive "more_set_headers" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:53

**Update-2 :**
`cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list` returns:

> deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian buster nginx

Comment: What does `apt-cache show nginx-extras` show as version?

Comment: What's the output of 
`dpkg -s nginx-extras | grep '^Version:'`?

Comment: Post updated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the nginx package instead of the extras package if you want to use the [nginx install page](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#Debian)

The 1.14 package for nginx-extras is coming from the base repo of debian.

You can install separate module like this:

`apt-get install libnginx-mod-http-headers-more-filter`

Comment: Would you mind telling me how to change the `Nginx-extras` repo ? Before running the code `apt-get install nginx-extras` what should I do to change the base repo of debian ?

Comment: You already have it installed. You probably don't need the nginx-extras. `apt-get remove nginx-extras && apt-get install nginx` will probably do it for you.

Comment: Thanks. After `sudo apt-get purge nginx-common nginx-extras` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get remove nginx nginx-common` and following instructions : http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#Debian and installing Nginx 1.20, and then installing `apt-get install nginx-extras` , still error on `more_set_headers directive is unknown` means that `problem in nginx-extras ver 1.14

Comment: Why do you install nginx-extras? The package should not be needed.

Comment: Thanks for taking time. To resolve `more_set_headers directive is unknown` I used to install `nginx-extras` on Ubuntu  and now I do it in Debian. and to use the `delay` in rate limiting, I need Nginx version's higher than default Repo which is 1.14.

Comment: Remove it and use the seperate packages `apt-get install libnginx-mod-http-headers-more-filter`